# I am working on Ublox C099-F9P board for rover base operation. I want to know how can I get received value on base on arduino using UART pins?

Tags: serial-communication

I have created a base and rover connection using C099-F9P boards. I am receiving the rover transmitted values on the base board's ODIN-W2 COM. I need to send these values to Arduino board using the UART pins. I have connected the TX-ODIN pin (C099-F9p board) to TX pin (Arduino). I am receiving the data but it is unformatted/garbage. I have attached the image to show it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or am I missing something? There is really less information on the Internet on how to transfer the ublox c099 board data to Arduino using serial pins. If anyone who has worked on this board can help me with this issue. Thanks
[The image shows COM8 which is rover data displayed, and COM5 which is Arduino COM port. Note that Arduino is connected with Base board using the serial pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZy6i.png)

Comment: To make a serial connection, you will need to connect Rx->Tx, Tx->Rx. In your question you wrote Tx->Tx, is that a typo?

Comment: @mhopeng 
If I connect Tx (GPS) to Tx(Arduino), I can read the transmitted data from the GPS directly on the serial monitor without any code.
Whereas,  if I connect Rx (GPS) to Tx(Arduino) I have to write code. Therefore it is good to do it directly without code.